# Setting MoveIt! controller manager

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the best available document for setting controller manager for MoveIt! is available from [this QA post](http://answers.ros.org/question/167501/how-to-solve-parameter-moveit_controller_manager-not-specified/), which is not sufficient for me to do my task. Is there another document for this?

I have a controller (w/o source code) that takes [trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory](http://docs.ros.org/api/trajectory_msgs/html/msg/JointTrajectory.html). I tried controller manager setting as below but still get the error.:

```
Created 99 (49 start + 50 goal) states in 75 cells (40 start (40 on boundary) + 35 goal (35 on boundary))
[ INFO] [1413825616.200813156]: Solution found in 0.828512 seconds
[ INFO] [1413825616.284702791]: Path simplification took 0.083540 seconds
[ INFO] [1413825625.393148074]: Received new trajectory execution service request...
[ERROR] [1413825625.393265662]: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: [ CARM/ELBOW_P CARM/LINEAR CARM/SHOULDER_P CARM/SHOULDER_R CARM/SHOULDER_Y CARM/WRIST_P CARM/WRIST_R CARM/WRIST_Y ]
```

Some values are just my random guess from looking at what others do (eg. [maxwell](https://github.com/mikeferguson/maxwell/tree/indigo-devel/maxwell_moveit_config/config), [pr2](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/PR2/Execution_of_Trajectories_with_MoveIt!)).

X_moveit_config/config/controllers.yaml

```
controller_list:
  - name: arm_controller            # Can it be anything or is this specified somewhere?
    action_ns: joint_trajectory     # Can it be anything or is this specified somewhere?
    type: JointTrajectory
    default: true
    joints:
      - ARMGR/LINEAR
      - ARMGR/SHOULDER_Y
      - ARMGR/SHOULDER_R
      - ARMGR/SHOULDER_P
      - ARMGR/ELBOW_P
      - ARMGR/WRIST_Y
      - ARMGR/WRIST_R
      - ARMGR/WRIST_P
  - name: gripper_controller        # Can it be anything or is this specified somewhere?
    type: HandMove
    action_ns: gripper_action       # Can it be anything or is this specified somewhere?
    default: true
    joints:
      - ARMGR/HAND/JOINT_1
      - ARMGR/HAND/JOINT_2
```

X_moveit_config/launch/X_moveit_controller_manager.launch

```
<!-- Set the param that trajectory_execution_manager needs to find the controller plugin -->
<arg name="moveit_controller_manager" default="moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager" />
<param name="moveit_controller_manager" value="$(arg moveit_controller_manager)"/>

<!-- load controller_list -->
<rosparam file="$(find X_moveit_config)/config/controllers.yaml"/>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195387/setting-moveit!-controller-manager/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2014-10-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [denim_patel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24047/denim_patel/) on 2016-01-02**:
is it solved?,if yes, then can you just give the summary of procedure?

**Comment by [anonymous28838](https://answers.ros.org/users/28838/anonymous28838/) on 2017-07-07**:
The documentation on this is lacking and tutorials insufficient. Any luck in finding a good tutorial on MoveIt with non-pr2 robots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might help:
http://answers.ros.org/question/192739/implement-moveit-on-real-robot/

---

Originally posted by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) with karma: 327 on 2014-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0